# Using Cloud Vision for live feed camera text detection

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision, text-recognition

So im trying to use cloud vision to detect text from live feed webcam input, but the delay was astonishing, about 6-7s delay for a single frame.

Is there any way to speed up that process?

Comment: How is the 6-7 seconds broken down? Eg: time over the network vs time extracting a frame and do any preprocessing. There is also the time to fetch credentials on the first request so may be more accurate to time after the first request. Do you have any code samples?